# Running a PowerShell script as a scheduled task produces different results

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-ise

I am running Windows Server 2012 used as an admin server. Here I have it setup to run PowerShell scrips as scheduled tasks to do various tasks on remote servers using Windows Remote Management *aka* Remote PowerShell.

The following script is one of 4 scripts, where underneath ############# everything stays exactly the same. Above ############# is where I set the different variables to run against different servers.

I have a problem where if I run one of the 4 scripts as a scheduled task, it persists in telling me the opposite result to what the result should be. All other scheduled task scripts run perfectly giving expected results. This script runs perfectly with expected results if I run it from PowerShell ISE *an email to say the **adfssrv** service is running*. However when this exact script is run using a scheduled task, I get an email to say the **adfssrv** service isn't running and it waits for 15 minutes before telling me again in an email that the **adfssrv** service is not running.

The Scheduled task is setup exactly the same as the others, **powershell.exe -command c:\Scripts\XA-US-FS-02_adfssrv.ps1** with all scripts locacted in the exact same local directory **c:\Scripts**

```
$FirstCheck = @()
$arrService = @()
$computername = @()
$MyHost = @()
$cred = @()
$password = @()
$cmdAutoAdmin = @()
$WinRMPort = @()
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "some_password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xa-us-fs-02\svc.tasks", $password )
$computername = "xa-us-fs-02.cloudapp.net"
$cmdAutoAdmin = {Get-Service -Name adfssrv}
$WinRMPort = 61573
$MyHost = "XA-US-FS-02"

$mytime = Get-Date -displayhint time
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "SendGridPassword");
$EmailFrom = "Email_Alerts@xyz.com"
$EmailTo = "receiver@xyz.com"

#########################################

$arrService = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Port $WinRMPort -Credential $cred -UseSSL -ScriptBlock $cmdAutoAdmin

 if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
    $Subject = "$MyHost - ADFS service" 
    $Body = "Hi, I just checked the ADFS service (adfssrv) on $MyHost at $mytime and it is running :)" 
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
    $FirstCheck = "Success"
 }

 elseif ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Port $WinRMPort -Credential $cred -UseSSL -ScriptBlock {Start-Service -Name adfssrv}
    $Subject = "$MyHost - ADFS NOT RUNNING" 
    $Body = "This is an email to say that the ADFS service on $MyHost was checked at $mytime and it was not started. `
    I have attempted to start the ADFS service just now. `
    I will check again in 15 minutes" 
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 900
}
            if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running" -and $FirstCheck -ne "Success"){
            $Subject = "$MyHost - ADFS NOT RUNNING AGAIN!" 
            $Body = "This is the SECOND email to say that the ADFS service on $MyHost was checked at $mytime and it was not started. `
            Manual human intervention required"
            $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
         }
            elseif ($arrService.Status -eq "Running" -and $FirstCheck -ne "Success"){
            $Subject = "$MyHost - ADFS service" 
            $Body = "Hi, I just checked the ADFS service (adfssrv) for a SECOND time on $MyHost at $mytime and it is now running :)" 
            $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
         }
```

Comment: Try changing your email to tell you exactly what the status is.  All you know right now is that $arrService.Status is not 'Running'.  You'd get the same result if it wasn't able to get the status at all, and $arrService.Status is null.

Comment: How would I add $arrService.Status into the line of text which gets sent to me as an email, and for the value of $arrService.Status to be shown in the email received?

Comment: I added in $MyStatus = $arrService.Status, then in the email I added $MyStatus to the line of text. Running the script now in PowerShell ISE, the email tells me the status of Running, but if I run the script as a scheduled task it tells me the status of " " (blank) or (nothing)

Comment: Add a start-transcript at the beginning of the script, then check the transcript file for errors after it runs.

Comment: Very nice tip, adding Start-Transcript at the beginning of the script, logged the exact error. Problem was with the SSL certificate on the remote machine, the SSL certificate was signed by an unknown certificate authority. Which also explains why it the script was running okay from PowerShell ISE (running as my user account) and not as a Scheduled task (another services account). The certificate on the local machine was only situated in the personal Trusted root certificate store. As soon as I copied the remote computer's certificate to the local computer's trusted root store, it worked.

Comment: Out of interest, virtually all your variable definitions are incorrectly typed.  Why are they all typed as arrays?